# fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in eval()

Tags: php, fclose

I am receiving this error **fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in eval()** is `$file` not the resource?

```
<?php $file = fgetcsv(fopen("https://www.example.com/tock.txt","r")); ?>
<div class="stocks-status"><div><div class="stocks-title">Books</div><div class="stockbook">

<?php echo $file[0]; ?></div></div><div><div class="stockbook">

<?php echo $file[1]; ?></div><div class="book-date"><span>

<?php echo $file[2]; ?></span> | <span>
<?php echo preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '${1} ', strtoupper($file[3])); ?> VIN</span></div></div></div><p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php fclose($file); ?>
```

Comment: You're not assigning the file pointer to a variable, so you can't close it.

Comment: `$file` is not the resource, it is the array returned by `fgetcsv()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fclose()` expects the file handle, you're passing the file contents. You want something like this:

```
$handle = fopen("https://www.example.com/tock.txt", "r");
$csv = fgetcsv($handle);
fclose($handle);
```

Note:

- You generally don't need to call `fclose()`, as it fires implicitly at the end of the script.
- You'll need to call `fgetcsv()` more than once if the file contains more than one line.

Also, the use of `eval()` should be avoided whenever possible. It usually introduces significant security concerns.